# merging multiple rows into one based on id

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

i have the data in this format in an amazon redshift database:

| id | answer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | house |
| 1 | apple |
| 1 | moon |
| 1 | money |
| 2 | 123 |
| 2 | xyz |
| 2 | abc |

and what i am looking for would be:

| id | answer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | house, apple, moon, money |
| 2 | 123, xyz, abc |

any idea? the thing is that i cannot hard code the answers as they will be variable, so preferably a solution that would simply scoop the answers for each id's row and put them together separated by a delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use aggregate function `listagg`:

```
select id , listagg(answer,',')
from table 
group by id
```

Comment: Good answer.  Be aware that listagg() will error if the resulting string is longer than the max varchar size.  This solution works well up to a point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_agg(concat(answer,''),',')` with `group by` so it will be like that:

```
select id , string_agg(concat(answer,''),',') as answer 
from table 
group by id
```

[tested here](https://sqliteonline.com/)

Edit:
you don't need concatenate, you can just  use `string_agg(answer,',')`

Comment: The efforts put in to answer the question are highly appreciated. Great! However, it would be really nice to pay attention to the format of the code. Yes, the SQL commands are not case-sensitive. But, that does not refrain us from writing it in a more formatted way. Either the commands can be fully in uppercase or fully in lower case.